# Unable to View/Add the Plugins inside Plugin Tab - Only Office

Tags: docker, document, cpu-word, onlyoffice

I have downloaded a fresh image of only office using docker and followed the python example. I have successfully opened the document in the editor but unable to view the plugins tab. Also, I have mounted the sdkjs-plugins volume on my local machine and added plugins manually but nothing worked. Please advise what I am missing during the installation.

Docker Command:

```
sudo docker run -i -t -d -p 8009:80 --restart=always \
    -v /app/onlyoffice/DocumentServer/logs:/var/log/onlyoffice  \
    -v /app/onlyoffice/DocumentServer/data:/var/www/onlyoffice/Data  \
    -v /app/onlyoffice/DocumentServer/lib:/var/lib/onlyoffice \
    -v /app/onlyoffice/DocumentServer/db:/var/lib/postgresql \ 
    -v /app/onlyoffice/DocumentServer/plugins:/var/www/onlyoffice/documentserver/sdkjs-plugins onlyoffice/documentserver-de
```

Plugins not available in Docker Container:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need default plugins set of the ONLYOFFICE Editors, just remove `-v /app/onlyoffice/DocumentServer/plugins:/var/www/onlyoffice/documentserver/sdkjs-plugins`

In case you are going to use your own plugins, please make sure that you have them in the mapped ***/app/onlyoffice/DocumentServer/plugins*** directory.

Comment: Actually, I needed both. So at first, I copied the default plugins from the container to my local machine and after that, I mounted that volume and put all plugins in the mapped directory.